# Geometry word problem shapes, volume

Tags: geometry

[image]

How do I find the volume of the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Volume = (area of base) $\times$ height.

Volume needed/given (old box with base dimensions $2\times 6$, and height $h = 10$):
 $V = (2 \times 6) \times 10 = 120\;$ cubic inches.

Now, you want a new a box with a *base area of* $\;b = (3 \times 5) = 15\;$ squared inches, and need to find height, while keeping the volume of $120$ cubic inches constant:

Again, as given, Volume is $\;V$ = (area of base) $\times $ height $(h)$, i.e. $\;\;V = b\times h$

We know $V$ and we know $b$, so we plug those values in and solve for $h$, height of new box.

$$V = 120 = 15 \times h \quad\implies\quad h = 120/15 = 8 \text{ inches}$$

Comment: Many thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, Little Jon!

Comment: It looks like a school problem! isn't it? +